# C#: My App's Font doesn't change. (when the code runs it is not apply the changes in the form)

Tags: c#

I downloaded `Material Skin` using `NuGet`.

Then, I made a prettier form design using the `material skin`.

However, there is a problem in my project that the font does not change.

For example if changing the font size, font family in the properties, it do applies in the design view but when the code runs it is not apply the changes in the form.

This is my source code:

```
using MaterialSkin.Controls;
using MaterialSkin;

public partial class Main : MaterialForm
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
        materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
        materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900, Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);

        this.Label1.font = new Font("Arial", 30f, FontStyle.Bold);
        this.Label2.font = new Font("Arial", 18f, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

My `material label(Label 1, Label 2)` font does not change unconditionally in the `Roboto` font.

However, It is able to change the font in `System.Windows.Forms.label` object.

I can't understand this problem.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material skin object's font is set in the materialSkinManager.

Thus, I think it's impossible to change font in material skin object directly.

however, If you want to replace all fonts, you can try this code:

```
var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900, Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);

// Code added by me
materialSkinManager.ROBOTO_REGULAR_11 = new Font("Arial", 30f, FontStyle.Regular);
materialSkinManager.ROBOTO_MEDIUM_12 = new Font("Arial", 30f, FontStyle.Bold);
materialSkinManager.ROBOTO_MEDIUM_11 = new Font("Arial", 30f, FontStyle.Regular);
materialSkinManager.ROBOTO_MEDIUM_10 = new Font("Arial", 30f, FontStyle.Bold);
```

I checked that this c# code able to used with MaterialSkin 0.2.2

Thank you.

Comment: but it changes only font size, but not widget that even set to autosize